# Ubuntu 11.10 won't let me login; it kicks me back to login screen

Tags: unity, command-line, login

I was just copying files from my external HDD to my .wine directory, when I noticed the place where the launchers are (Unity desktop) was getting fuzzy and holding onto graphics from the things in the location prior(i have it autohide when a window covers it). I assumed it was just RAM problem, so I canceled the copying, since it wasn't actually important. The glitch remained, and so did another; very slow response time. The mouse moved just fine, but windows were waiting about a minute after I hit the x button to close or even switch active window. Once again, I blamed RAM (only have 2 GBs) so I restarted.

Usually, it autologs me into my account, since I'm the only user, but this time it presented me with the login screen. I thought it odd, but tried to log in. A black screen with some text pops up (assuming terminal screen) for half a second then kicks me back to the login screen. I tried the guest account and no luck. I went into terminal (alt+ctrl+f1) and logged in and it worked. I deleted .Xauthority, made new account, and even rebooted quite a few times, all to no avail. Anyone have an idea?